# Can't connect localhost using WAGMI "HttpRequestError: HTTP request failed."

Tags: typescript, wagmi

So I'm trying to call functions by using wagmi.
I tried on goerli and the code works fine,both smart contract and wagmi.
now I'm going to use it on my private chain that I had already setup on my localhost:8545
but after I tried to `npm run dev` and run the website,then it jumped error
So apperently ,wagmi couldn't connect or request to my localhost chain

**error code**:

```
ContractFunctionExecutionError: HTTP request failed.

URL: http://127.0.0.1:8545
Request body: {"method":"eth_call","params":[{"data":"0x2e64cec1","to":"0x654717d19E9EF3dA2b15940053Ef02dD185f9795"},"latest"]}
 
Raw Call Arguments:
  to:    0x654717d19E9EF3dA2b15940053Ef02dD185f9795
  data:  0x2e64cec1
 
Contract Call:
  address:   0x654717d19E9EF3dA2b15940053Ef02dD185f9795
  function:  retrieve()

Docs: https://viem.sh/docs/contract/readContract.html
Details: Failed to fetch
Version: viem@1.2.15
```

in **_app.js**:

```
const { chains, publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(
  [localhost],
  [publicProvider()]
)
const config = createConfig({
    autoConnect: true,
    connectors, //I use rainbowKit
    publicClient,
    webSocketPublicClient,
  });
```

in **index.js**

```
const data = await readContract({
  address:'0x654717d19E9EF3dA2b15940053Ef02dD185f9795',
  abi: [
    {"inputs":[],"name":"retrieve","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}
  ],
  functionName: 'retrieve',
})

// more code

const handleClick = () => {
    console.log(data)
  }
```

**contract.sol**:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SimpleContract{
    
    uint256 public value = 5;
    uint256 public value_ = 7;

    function set(uint256 number) public returns(uint256) {
        value = number;
        return value;
    }

    function retrieve() view public returns(uint256) {
        return value;
    }

    function retrievebyindex(uint8 index) view public returns(uint256) {
        if(index == 0)
            return value;
        else 
            return value_;
    }

    fallback() external{}

}
```

I only snipped the code that might occur this problem,maybe there's other code that will affect on this,please let me know

so I tried using json rpc,but it still failed on requesting HTTP,its the same error
**app.js**

```
 
const { chains, publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(
  [localhost],
  [
    jsonRpcProvider({
      rpc: (chain) => ({
        http: `http://127.0.0.1:8545`,
      }),
    }),
  ],
)
```

I tried to give some token from geth account to my metamask account and yes,metamask can get the balance properly

[image: metamask balance]
[image]
so I just want to let wagmi to connect to my localhost chain so I kept going